# Create excel formula to validate the assessor as having completed the course themselves?

Tags: excel, indexing, match, training-data

I'm trying to create one or more formulas - probably need combined match/index (within columns L+) so that the assessor (column K) can be validated as having undertaken the same course themselves (column J).  Once this has been confirmed, i then need to ensure that the assessor's own training is in date (column H).

This is my first post, happy to attach graphic but apparently need 10 reputation points to do so.

```
Name:       Job:    IssueDate:  ReturnDate: Update Due: TrainingInDate: Competency: Assessors Name: 
Scooby Doo  Job 1   30/09/2010  29/09/2012              expired         Course A    Tig Ger 
Scooby Doo  Job 1   09/10/2013  09/10/2013  09/10/2015  in date         Course B    Tig Ger     
Scooby Doo  Job 1   12/11/2013  12/11/2013  12/11/2015  in date         Course C    Mister Blobby       
Scooby Doo  Job 1   12/11/2013  12/11/2015              in date         Course D    Tig Ger     
Tig Ger     Job 1   04/02/2010  30/12/1901              expired         Course A            
Tig Ger     Job 1   06/05/2010  14/01/2011  05/05/2012  expired         Course B            
Tig Ger     Job 1   17/11/2010  14/01/2011  16/11/2012  expired         Course C            
Winnie Pooh Job 2   19/04/2011  18/04/2013              expired         Course A    Tig Ger     
Winnie Pooh Job 2   10/09/2013  10/09/2015              in date         Course B    Tig Ger     
Winnie Pooh Job 2   01/09/2013  16/08/2011  01/09/2015  in date         Course C    Scooby Doo      
Winnie Pooh Job 2   20/10/2011  27/08/2011  19/10/2013  expired         Course D    Scooby Doo
```

Comment: I've tried the match/index options but have struggled to make them work

Comment: This relates to an extract from a training record. Assessors can be peers, but only if they have undertaken the training themselves and are still in date.   I;d like this data to be shown In column/s to the right of the data grid, - happy for this to be a multi-stage process - i would like confirmation that 1) the assessor has undertaken the course themself ie row 1, assessor Tigger has also undertaken Course A (row 5). and 2) that the assessors course is currently in date.  thanks

Comment: thanks for this.  Could i please confirm which columns you're referring to as when i ran it i ended up with a column of 0's.  is:   A-name, K-assessor, J-course?

Comment: solved this - needed two concatenate formulas - one to merge the assessor & course, the other to merge the delegate & course name.  these were then crossreferenced using index/match